# Output Arraylist String without brackets and commas

Tags: java, arraylist, user-input

I'm trying to write a program that reads a string of text and prints all digrams in this text and their frequencies.

Example of input: `park car at the parking lot`

Corresponding output: `ar:3 pa:2 rk:2 at:1 ca:1 he:1 in:1 ki:1 lo:1 ng:1 ot:1 th:1`

When I try this sample input, it outputs `[ar:3, pa:2, rk:2, ca:1, at:1, th:1, he:1, ki:1, in:1, ng:1, lo:1, ot:1]`

How do I fix this so it wont have brackets and commas?

```
public class Digrams {

public static void main(String args[]) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    String str = scan.nextLine();

    ArrayList<String> repetition = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> digrams = new ArrayList<String>();
    String digram;

    for (int i = 0; i < str.length() - 1; i++) {
        digram = str.substring(i, i + 2);
        if (repetition.contains(digram) || digram.contains(" ") || digram.length() < 2) {
            continue;
        }
        int occurances = (str.length() - str.replace(digram, "").length()) / 2;
        digrams.add(digram + ":" + occurances);
        repetition.add(digram);
    }

    Collections.sort(digrams, (s1, s2) -> s2.substring(3, 4).compareTo(s1.substring(3, 4)));

    System.out.println(digrams);
  }
}
```

Comment: You'll have to write a custom method to do this. `ArrayList`'s `toString()` method is what adds the brackets and commas.

Answer (score 2):

not the most efficient solution but it will do the job.

```
String result = digrams.toString();
System.out.println(result.replaceAll(",","").replace("[","").replace("]",""));
```

Comment: suppose for `result.replaceAll(",","")` because it has many `,`.(+1)

Comment: sure thing. though both will do the job.